# Cant find directory /app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/ in magento 1.6.0

Tags: magento

I'm new to Magento and I am now studying magento module development and in almost all the ebooks I bought on amazon and other tutorials I have read.

I've been asked to change the values in this files under:

```
/app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/
```

to be shown on frontend (customer page). Yet the directory under:

```
/app/design/frontend/default/default/
```

is only:

```
/app/design/frontend/default/default/etc
```

and:

```
/app/design/frontend/default/default/locale
```

I'm using Megento version 1.6.0, I dont know if I'm doing something wrong or I am not looking hard enough. I feel like there has been a change in the directory structure for the frontend. Please someone should explain things to me a little bit so I can go on with my development.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the default clean install, the files you are looking for are probably in: `app\design\frontend\base\default\`

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer but if i may ask, under what condition or circumstances would it change back from  app\design\frontend\base\default\template to /app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/ as you pointed out that if it is a clean install.

Comment: default/default can be used for overriding (but not recommended). If Mage can't find the files in default/default, it will then look for them in base. So, if you were to edit certain templates, I'd extend them by copying them out of base into your own namespace.

Comment: Thank you very much @djdy, you **saved** me a whole day of frustration.

Comment: @JeanLinux glad to help. When you get a chance, please accept the answer.